# Flags description uses different number of moderators

Tags: bug, flags, wording, plurals

There is inconsistency with the number of moderators in the recently added section for [flag description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/current) (emphasis is mine):

- helpful

  > A "helpful" flag is one that **moderators** or other trusted members of the community found informative or actionable.
- declined

  > Flags are "declined" when a **moderator** or other trusted members of the community decline to act on them.

Comment: Time to break out the tiny self adhesive Ses?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek just don't want to translate the string multiple times due to changing the English text.